# Packet Sockets not receiving data for custom protocol ID

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to send and receive packets of type `SOCK_RAW` over `PF_SOCKET`s using my own custom protocol ID on the same machine. Here is my sender and receiver sample code-

sender.c

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<linux/if_packet.h>
#include<linux/if_ether.h>
#include<linux/if_arp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define CUSTOM_PROTO 0xB588

int main ()
{
    int sockfd = -1;
    struct sockaddr_ll dest_addr = {0}, src_addr={0};
    char *buffer = NULL;
    struct ethhdr *eh;

    sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(CUSTOM_PROTO) );

    if ( sockfd == -1 )
    {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    buffer = malloc(1518);
    eh = (struct ethhdr *)buffer;

    dest_addr.sll_ifindex  = if_nametoindex("eth0");
    dest_addr.sll_addr[0]  = 0x0;
    dest_addr.sll_addr[1]  = 0xc;
    dest_addr.sll_addr[2]  = 0x29;
    dest_addr.sll_addr[3]  = 0x49;
    dest_addr.sll_addr[4]  = 0x3f;
    dest_addr.sll_addr[5]  = 0x5b;
    dest_addr.sll_addr[6]  = 0x0;
    dest_addr.sll_addr[7]  = 0x0;

    //other host MAC address
    unsigned char dest_mac[6] = {0x0, 0xc, 0x29, 0x49, 0x3f, 0x5b};

    /*set the frame header*/
    memcpy((void*)buffer, (void*)dest_mac, ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy((void*)(buffer+ETH_ALEN), (void*)dest_mac, ETH_ALEN);

    eh->h_proto = htons(PAVAN_PROTO);

    memcpy((void*)(buffer+ETH_ALEN+ETH_ALEN + 2), "Pavan", 6 );

    int send = sendto(sockfd, buffer, 1514, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest_addr,
                      sizeof(dest_addr) );
    if ( send == -1 )
    {
        perror("sendto");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

receiver.c

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<linux/if_packet.h>
#include<linux/if_ether.h>
#include<linux/if_arp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define CUSTOM_PROTO 0xB588

int main ()
{
    int sockfd = -1;
    struct sockaddr_ll dest_addr = {0}, src_addr={0};
    char *recvbuf = malloc(1514);

    sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(CUSTOM_PROTO) );

    if ( sockfd == -1 )
    {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    int len = recvfrom(sockfd, recvbuf, 1514, 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("I received: \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Both sender and receiver are running on Ubuntu Virtualbox. The problem is the receiver hangs in `recvfrom`. But in `receiver.c`, if I change `htons(CUSTOM_PROTO)` to `htons(ETH_P_ALL)`, the receiver works just fine.

Why is the kernel not delivering the packet with my custom protocol ID to my custom protocol ID socket?

I verified in GDB that the ethernet header is formed correctly when I receive packet with `htons(ETH_P_ALL)`

**Update:** Instead of interface `eth0` and its corresponding MAC, if I choose local loopback `lo` and a MAC address of `00:00:00:00:00:00`, `CUSTOM_PROTO` works just fine!

**Update 2** `CUSTOM_PROTO` works fine if the sender and receiver are on different machines. This finding and prev update made me suspect that packets being sent out on `eth0` are not being received by the same machine. But the fact that `ETH_P_ALL` works on the same machine, refutes my suspicion.

Comment: Do you REALLY need a custom transport protocol?  Just a cursory search on the web suggests you need to write kernel level code to deal with this.  See this question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760017/addition-of-a-new-network-protocol-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: @RussSchultz Actually this is for a course assignment. All of us will be running our code on the same machines as root. We need to use unique protocol IDs to distinguish our packets

Comment: @RussSchultz In the link you give, they want to handle the new protocol in the kernel and hence all the kernel code. Here, I will do all processing in user space. I dont want the kernel to do anything with my packets except sending packets with my ID to my socket

Comment: 0xffff is reserved (for whatever purposes). Try 0x88b5 or 0x88b6 which are specifically reserved for private and experimental use.

Comment: @user58697 Tried. Even tried 0xB588 and 0xB688 just in case you meant network order. No luck with both.

Comment: I also presume that `PAVAN_PROTO` is the same as `CUSTOM_PROTO`.

Comment: @user58697 Oops. That was a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: You tried to use `tcpdump` or other similar tool to check the traffic? There's some rule that could be blocking the packets?

Comment: @PavanManjunath Can you post in minimal form we can easily compile and run to verify without screwing around please?

Comment: @S.Pinkus Done. Have added compilable code. Just check the MAC address to the one on your machine

Comment: I am curious what happens if you are not running on VirtualBox and whether the loopback then works properly.  there seems to be a few workarounds for some networking applications with VirtualBox https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Networking however it is all new to me so maybe it is a lack of experience on my part.

Comment: @RichardChambers I tried it on VMs with public IPs. Same result. And I need to get this to work on VMs.

Comment: I understand you need it to work on VirtualBox. I suggest you try it on bare metal first to see if it works or not. If not then implied is there is a problem with your code. If it does work then implied is there is some kind of configuration problem with VirtualBox or it is not supported by VirtualBox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### ETH_P_ALL vs any other protocol

The protocol `ETH_P_ALL` has the special role of capturing outgoing packets.

Receiver socket with any protocol that is not equal to `ETH_P_ALL` receives packets of that protocol that come from the device driver.

Socket with protocol `ETH_P_ALL` receives all packets before sending outgoing packets to the device driver and all incoming packets that are received from the device driver.

### Loopback device vs Ethernet device

Packets sent to the loopback device go out from that device and then the same packets are received from the device as incoming.
So, when `CUSTOM_PROTO` is used with loopback the socket captures packets with custom protocol as incoming.

**Note that if `ETH_P_ALL` is used with the loopback device each packet is received twice.** Once it is captured as outgoing and the second time as incoming.

In case of `eth0` the packet is transmitted from the device. So, such packets go to the device driver and then they can be seen on the other side of the physical Ethernet port. For example, with VirtualBox "Host-only" network adapter those packets can be captured by some sniffer in the host system.

However, packets transmitted to the physical port (or its emulation) are not redirected back to that port. So, they are not received as incoming from the device. That is why such packets can be captured only by `ETH_P_ALL` in outgoing direction and they cannot be seen by `CUSTOM_PROTO` in incoming direction.

Technically it should possible to prepare special setup to do external packet loopback (packets from the device port should be sent back to that port). In that case the behavior should be similar to the loopback device.

### Kernel implementation

See the kernel file [`net/core/dev.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/dev.c?v=3.19#L149). There are two different lists:

```
struct list_head ptype_base[PTYPE_HASH_SIZE] __read_mostly;
struct list_head ptype_all __read_mostly;   /* Taps */
```

The list `ptype_all` is for socket handlers with protocol `ETH_P_ALL`. The list `ptype_base` is for handlers with normal protocols.

There is a hook for outgoing packets in [`xmit_one()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/dev.c?v=3.19#L2591) called from [`dev_hard_start_xmit()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/dev.c?v=3.19#L2612):

```
    if (!list_empty(&ptype_all))
        dev_queue_xmit_nit(skb, dev);
```

For outgoing packets the function `dev_queue_xmit_nit()` is called for `ETH_P_ALL` processing each item of `ptype_all`. Finally the sockets of type `AF_SOCKET` with protocol `ETH_P_ALL` capture that outgoing packet.

---

So, the observed behavior is not related to any custom protocol. The same behavior can be observed with `ETH_P_IP`. In that case the receiver is able to capture all incoming IP packets, however it cannot capture IP packets from `sender.c` that sends from `"eth0"` to MAC address of `"eth0"` device.

It can be also seen by `tcpdump`. The packets sent by the sender are not captured if `tcpdump` is called with an option to capture only incoming packets (different versions of `tcpdump` use different command line argument to enable such filtering).

---

The initial task where on the same machines it is needed to distinguish packets by protocol IDs can be solved using `ETH_P_ALL`. The receiver should capture all packets and check the protocol, for example:

```
while (1) {
    int len = recvfrom(sockfd, recvbuf, 1514, 0, NULL, NULL);

    if (ntohs(*(uint16_t*)(recvbuf + ETH_ALEN + ETH_ALEN)) == CUSTOM_PROTO) {
        printf("I received: \n");
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Useful reference ["kernel_flow"](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/kernel_flow) with a nice diagram http://www.linuxfoundation.org/images/1/1c/Network_data_flow_through_kernel.png

It is based on the 2.6.20 kernel, however in the modern kernels `ETH_P_ALL` is treated in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont get you completely. Do you mean that only if the type is ETH_P_ALL does the kernel capture the outgoing packet? What happens to the packet if its any other proto? The packet is supposed to go out of eth0 and come (back) to eth0. Isn't this packet treated as incoming packet?

Comment: @PavanManjunath Yes, all packets of all protocols in both directions (in and out) are captured by socket with `ETH_P_ALL`. So, in your tests you are able to capture that packet only from outgoing queue. That packet is never received as incoming on the `eth0` device. If the receiving socket is opened with `CUSTOM_PROTO` it can receive only packets that are indeed received through `eth0` from outside.

Comment: In the above code, I put the `recvfrom` in a while(1) loop and set ETH_P_ALL. I am not receiving  2 packets per sent packet. Did you notice the duplicate packets on the same code I've posted? If not can you please paste your code somewhere on pastebin? (cos answer is very big already :))

Comment: @PavanManjunath Duplicate packets only for **loopback** device. In `sender.c`: `dest_addr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("lo");` `unsigned char dest_mac[6] = { 0 };` (`dest_addr.sll_addr[]` should not be set, because it is already zero: `dest_addr = {0}`).

Comment: You are right! Only the loopback is getting duped packets. I appreciate the thoroughly researched answer. Can you please link up the source files you've mentioned to actual linux kernel code @ free electrons or somewhere? That would allow users to explore more and make your answer more complete

Answer (score 0):

When packets with same source nad destination MAC address are transmitted from real network device `ethX` and physically looped back.

If protocol  `ETH_P_ALL` is specified, packet is captured twice:

- first packet with `socket_address.sll_pkttype` is `PACKET_OUTGOING`
- and second packet with `socket_address.sll_pkttype` is `PACKET_HOST`

If specific protocol is specified `CUSTOM_PROTO`, packet is captured once:

- in the case of normal packet: `socket_address.sll_pkttype`is
  `PACKET_HOST`.
- in the case of VLAN packet:
  `socket_address.sll_pkttype`is `PACKET_OTHERHOST`.