# C RAW socket communication with custom ETH type

Tags: c, linux, sockets

So I have two userspace applications (lets say app A and B) running on linux 2.6 kernel.

app A sends raw packet with a custom ethernet type (ETH_FOO) using the socket below

```
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_FOO));
```

if app B opens a raw socket with ETH_P_ALL and listens to all interfaces without binding, it can successfully receive pkts sent by A with type ETH_FOO.

But if B opens the socket with type ETH_FOO, no packet is observed. I just want to capture ETH_FOO pkts. What may be the problem?

This is my first question here. Pardon my mistakes if there is any. Also I can not copy the entire code since it's not mine and somewhat propriatery.

Comment: just tried. No change. Strange thing is I can capture ETH_FOO packets from several different kernel modules, but not from my application

Comment: What is the `ETH_FOO` value?

Comment: Do you run your application with root privilege? Do you have error checking after system calls?

Comment: ETH_FOO is 0x886c. yes error checking and root priviledges are ok. it just seems kernel doesn't like ETH_FOO pkts when I send them from a userspace app. I can capture same type of raw pkts with no problem when they are sent from a module.

Answer (score 1):

When you use ETH_P_ALL, you are listening all packets, both ingoing and outgoing.

If you are in the same machine, using the same network interface, when you send a packet, there is no ingoing packet. Using ETH_P_ALL will get you the outgoing packet.

When you specify other value than ETH_P_ALL, only incoming packets are listened to. And you get nothing if using the Ethernet interface in the same machine.

You have two options here:

- use different machines
- in the same machine, use the loopback adapter (which creates an ingoing packet for every outgoing packet). The loopback adapter is listed together with the Ethernet adapter when you type `ip a`.

It took me some time to learn this, and I did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484762/packet-sockets-not-receiving-data-for-custom-protocol-id/33657456#33657456), where you can learn a bit more.